# How will I condition my checkbox according to a status using jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a data where you can choose to activate it or inactivate it. The process when you want to choose a status is through a bootstrap toggle switch. I used checkbox to make the toggle switch. The problem is it is not working and I know why. Because it doesn't have an access to my checkbox, My goal is that inside my form if my data is active the checkbox will automatically be set "checked" and if inactive, the checkbox will be unchecked. Second problem is to my toggle switch is not working.

How can I set the checkbox checked if the status is active and how can I make automatically uncheck inside my form if status is Inactive?

How can I use the toggle switch from bootstrap properly?

What I've tried is to condition the checkboxes

Here is the code I've tried but still did not work

```
if(status == 1)
    {
        $("#update_chk").prop('checked', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#update_chk").prop('checked', false);
    }
```

Here is my code in HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="update_stats" id="update_chk" checked
 data-toggle="toggle"
 data-onstyle="<?php echo ($rows['status']) ? 'success' : 'danger'?>"
 data-offstyle="<?php echo ($rows['status']) ? 'danger' : 'success'?>"
 data-on="<?php if($rows['status'] == 1) { echo 'Active'; } else { echo 'Inactive'; }?>"
 data-off="<?php if($rows['status'] == 0) { echo 'Active'; } else { echo 'Inactive'; }?>"
 data-id="<?php echo $rows['ID'];?>"
 class="status_checks <?php echo ($rows['status']) ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'?>"
 value="1">
```

JQUERY code

```
    $(document).on('click', '.status_checks', function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    var status = '1';
    var selector = $(this);
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $("#reason").html("");
    // alert(id);

    if ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) {
        status = '0';

        $("#reason").append(
            '<div><label> Reason for making it inactive? </label><font color=red>*</font></div>');

        var input = $('<input>', {
            id: 'reason_elem',
            name: 'reason_input_elem',
            type: 'text',
            class: 'form-control has-error has-danger',
            focusin: function() {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        }).appendTo('#reason');
    }
    // alert(val);
    // alert(status);

    selector.hasClass("btn-success") ? (selector.removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger"),
        selector.text("Inactive")) : (selector.removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success"),
        selector.text("Active"));
});
```

[image]

[image: This is suppose to be uncheck if the data is inactive]

This is suppose to be unchecked if the data is inactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `removeAttr()` and `attr` to add `checked` or remove that attribute . Then , no need to change `text` from jquery code bootstrap toggle will do itself just specify `style` and `on/off` condition.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('change', '.status_checks', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var status = '1';
  var selector = $(this);
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $("#reason").html("");
  if ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) {
    status = '0';
    $("#reason").append(
      '<div><label> Reason for making it inactive? </label><font color=red>*</font></div>');

    var input = $('<input>', {
      id: 'reason_elem',
      name: 'reason_input_elem',
      type: 'text',
      class: 'form-control has-error has-danger',
      focusin: function() {
        $(this).val('');
      }
    }).appendTo('#reason');
  }
  console.log("is checked ?" + $(this).is(":checked"))
  //here remve and add checked attr
  selector.hasClass("btn-success") ? (selector.removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger"),
    selector.removeAttr("checked")) : (selector.removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success"),
    selector.attr('checked', 'checked'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<!--here for on state add active and for off state add inactive same for on and of style-->
<input type="checkbox" name="update_stats" id="update_chk" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-id="1" class="status_checks btn-success" value="1">

<div id="reason"></div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks :)) . I have other question. The button in my inactive form still has an active button, how should I make it remain inactive button? I added my previous code and get the ID and status but it doesn't follow.

Comment: so , if user select `inactive` then type reason.. that time status should not change ? are you submitting that value when user type inside input-box

Comment: which form ? edit ? .. not enough information .. please elaborate .

Comment: Wait sorry, it made us confused haha. When submitting reason in form it change status to 0. and reason is inserted in db, I have a partition of active and inactive of data inside my dataTable. I have a selection for active/inactive datas to be displayed. and then all datas are edittable.

Comment: and when edit, I change status when I click Inactive and when I go to the table of Inactive, the button should inactive. When I click again active the button is active and when click the data in active table the button is active, something like that.

Comment: still confusing . Asking another question would be good option because its not related to this question :)

Comment: Okay thanks for the help will ask another question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="width: 25px;">
 <input data-id="{{$book->id}}" data-forwhat="books" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox"  data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle"  data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive"  {{ $book->status ? 'checked' : '' }}>
 </td>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> 
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script> 


<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   console.log('jQuery is loaded!');
    $('.toggle-class').change(function(){
     var status =$(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
     var forwhat = $(this).data('forwhat') || 'books';
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   url: '/changeStatus',
   data: {
    'status': status,
   'id': id,
   'forwhat': forwhat,
    '_token': token
  },
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data.success)
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
 console.error(xhr.responseText);
  }
  })
 });
});
</script>

in route:
Route::get('/changeStatus',[ReligionAdminController::class,'status']);

in controller:
function status(Request $request){
        try{
        $model = new ReligionModel;
        $user=$model->setTable($request->forwhat)->find($request->id);
        $user->status = $request->status;
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Status change successfully.']); 
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle exceptions (e.g., database errors) here
            return response()->json(['error' => 'An error occurred.'], 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).